# Initial value problem by Picard's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2+cos^2x, x\gt 0$, y(0)=0, The largest interval of existence of the solution predicted by Picard's theorem is:

$\\1. \left[ 0,1\right] \\2. \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \\3. \left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right] \\4. \left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$

My attempt: Here the intial value is y(0)=0 and f(x)=$y^2+cos^2x$

Picard's method is 
 $y_{n+1}=y_0+\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y_n(t))$dt
hence
$y_1=0+\int_0^x(0+cos^2x)$dt

$y_1=\int_0^x\frac{1+cos2x}{2}$dt=$\frac{x}{2}+\frac{sin2x}{2}$

I don't how to check the largest interval of existence of the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation of the interval $[0,\delta]$ predicted by Picard's theorem is based on an a-priori estimate.

Namely, for the Cauchy problem with $y(0) = 0$, you can choose a compact rectangle $K := [0,a]\times[-R,R]$, compute
$$
M := \max\{|f(x,y)|:\ (x,y)\in K\}
$$
and then the predicted $\delta$ is given by
$$
\delta = \min\left\{a, \ \frac{R}{M}\right\}.
$$ 
In your case, you can choose $a>0$ large as you want, since
$$
M := \max\{|f(x,y)|:\ x\in[0,a],\ |y|\leq R\} = R^2 + 1
$$
is independent of $a$,
and get
$$
\delta = \frac{R}{R^2+1}\,.
$$
This $\delta$ is maximized by choosing $R=1$ (which gives $\delta = 1/2$).

Remark: the interval $[0,\delta]$ is not the maximal interval of existence of the solution (indeed, in this case one can prove that the solution is defined at least on the interval $[0, \pi/2$).